# How to install the right version of a package

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install a module for Angular 4.0.0 with node, but when I install it npm says `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.2.4`, so which is the best way to install the right version of a module, considering the versions of the dependencies that I already have installed.

Comment: New module would have listed angular 4.2.4 version in his peer dependencies (you can verify in package.json of that module.), but your package.json file has angular 4.0.0. you can get your old packages, by running "npm outdated".

Comment: In fact the module that I am installing only depends on angular 2.3^, may be other module installed previously?

Comment: UNMET means package is required, but not installed, the case you are talking should not show any warning, but 'npm prune' will delete extra installed packages.